# jQuery Hover and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, hover

I'm losing my hairline over something that's probably minute. If you compare [this website](http://goodfruitguide.co.uk/best-fruit-available-now) 
in Chrome/Firefox with IE, you'll notice that if you hover over each entry, in Chrome/FF it'll get a slight green background whereas in IE, zilch/nada/zero/zippo...

Can anyone in the coding fraternity give some pointers? Admittedly, jQuery is not my strong point and this is the code what's powering the hover effect:

```
$('div.availableNowListing').hover( function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
});
```

and the CSS:

```
div.availableNowListingCatHeading {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #efefef;}

div.availableNowListingCatHeading h3 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 20px;}

div.availableNowListingCatHeading img {
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;}

.focus {
    background-color: #dbfcab;}
```

Thanks in advance for taking a peek at this :)

Comment: I don't see any errors but could you take out `console.log` s from your page just in case?

Comment: You seem to be including jQuery twice on your page. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @Heikki - I've done console.log and it registers the hover effects fine, just doesn't display the green background. Grrr.

Comment: @Karim - The double inclusion is drove me mad as well, eventually giving up my hands in surrender. It's a WP based site, and one of the inclusions is from a plugin, the other one is a manual placement. The reason I did the manual placement is that without it, the jquery I placed in the footer (i'll link to an external js file later) wouldn't run at all, despite the plugin calling jquery. Also, I've set the jquery code copied above to work in noconflict mode - but I'm not sure it does anything if two jquery libraries are called :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the

```
header = $(this).find('div.availableNowListingCatHeading');
```

line.

You have a div with id of `header` and that confuses IE (*which treats the variable as a shortcut to the element.*)
This cause the IE to try to assign something to en element which fails and stops your script there. (*the `focus` class never gets assigned*)

Just add `var` at the beginning (*if you want to do something with it, or remove the line completely if it is a leftover*)..

```
var header = $(this).find('div.availableNowListingCatHeading');
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion (although I didn't understand why adding `var` fixed it), except I also had to comment out the `console.log()` calls to make it work in IE.

Comment: @thirtydot - yeah you need to have the developer tools running in IE to allow console.log

Comment: @thirtydot - adding `var` makes it into a new locally-scoped variable rather than using the global variable of the same name.

Comment: Gaby - thanks loads! That was the primary error in the script - just after removing the line, everything worked perfectly. There was, subsequent to this, CSS errors as mentioned by Fredrik that also fixed the display issue. Your solution ended up correctly applying the .focus class, and Fredrik's solution fixed the correct implementation of .focus due to floating elements inside :) - thanks loads!

Comment: @inrbob, also having the `firebug lite` loaded fixes the `console.log()` problem.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess it's due that `div.availableNowListing` doesn't get any height since you're floating the elements inside `div.availableNowListing`.

Set css property `overflow: hidden` on `div.availableNowListing` and try it out.

..fredrik

Comment: Hi Fredrik, thanks a bunch for answering - in combination with Gaby's answer I was able to fix the display. It ended being a combination of CSS / jQuery errors :)

Comment: @Gaby: needless to say, had same/similar problem more then once :)